# Dart name collision resolution

Tags: dart

I have a file in Dart that looks like this:

```dart
library myLibrary;

bool myFunction(String s) => s == null;

extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get myFunction=> myFunction(this);
}
```

Where I basically want to add extensions to previous existing functions, with the same name.

The Dart compiler complains about this, as it can't see the outer `myFunction()` name, just the getter, inside `StringExtensions`.

Is it there a way for me to reference the external `myFunction` from inside `StringExtensions`? Or can I just achieve this by separatting them in two different files/libraries using aliases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can import the file itself with an alias:

```dart
library myLibrary;

// file: my_library.dart
import "my_library.dart" as prefix;

bool myFunction(String s) => s == null;

extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get myFunction=> prefix.myFunction(this);
}
```

As shown [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1234).

Answer (score 3):

You could create a private reference to the function and use that inside your extension:

```
final _myFunction = myFunction;
extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get myFunction => _myFunction(this);
}
```

In order to avoid the overhead of creating private references, you can just create a new file for the extensions and import `myLibrary` using an alias:

```
import 'package:myLibrary/myLibrary.dart' as myLibray;

extension StringExtensions on String {
  bool get myFunction => myLibrary.myFunction(this);
}

...
```

Comment: Yeah, but I rather avoid the boilerplate, I have some 10 functions to extend.

Comment: @MichelFeinstein In that case, I suggest you go with the other idea you had, which is to create a separate file for the extension and import `myLibrary`.

Comment: That's what I did, I was just hoping Dart had a more elegant mechanism for this.

Comment: @MichelFeinstein In general, it probably would be a good idea to put extensions in separate Dart libraries anyway to make it easier to deal with possible name collisions with other extensions.